# Flink Kafka consumer StreamExecutionEnvironment only?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have pulling scenario,

**HTTP -> Kafka -> Flink -> some output**

If im not wrong i can use kafka consumer on stream only  ?

Therefor i need to "block"   the stream in order to sum/count the data im receiving from the HTTP call .

The easiest way to "block" is to add **window**/.

What is the best approach  for this pulling scenario .

**UPDATE**

I want to prevent from the collector to sum each value

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> t = 
        in.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(String s, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> 
            collector) throws Exception {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(s);
                node.elements().forEachRemaining(v -> {
                    collector.collect(new Tuple2<>(v.textValue(), 1));
                });

            }
        }).keyBy(0).sum(1);
```

Comment: What do you mean with block the stream? Do you want to block your HTTP requests?

Comment: @twalthr updated the question

Comment: Did you take a look into ProcessFunction? You can e.g. collect records in Flink's state and set a timer when to aggregate the data and finally emit it to the next operator.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I think what you may want to use is a session window. This will continue to collect messages into the window and will only process the contents of the window when an event hasn't been received after a certain amount of time. See the documentation on session windows here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html